# Laravel 5.1 Auth to get back the username in session?

Tags: laravel-5.1, laravel-authorization

I'm using laravel 5.1, there's method "Auth" can generate the login, register,etc...
But I have a question that how to get "that" username back as I wanted?

For example, I registered as,

> email: 123@123.com , name: 123

And in database, I have another table `profile`, laravel model : `Profile`, which contains:

> email: 123@123.com , sex: male

In here, I want to show "male" in the view.

1. How laravel work to find specify data across different table ?
2. Does Laravel has other "word" to represent "this(123@123.com)" when it was logged already (Auth) ?

Thanks!!

Comment: Have you read the docs? This is explained there

Answer (score 0):

Try using this code in your blade view to print sex.

```
{{ Auth::user()->sex; }}
```

And using this code to print email

```
{{ Auth::user()->email; }}
```

Hope this code works well.